# Android socket test, can only send hardcoded string

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am trying to set up a socket between my Application and a server.  I want my application to take in user input from a EditText and send it tot he server.  The server is working correctly.  Right now, I have a variable String str, and if I hardcode str to be "Who's there?", my application sends "Who's there?" to the server, and the server successfully receives it. But if I try to use String str = et.getText().toString(); it doesn't send anything to my server, regardless of what et's value is.  Below is my applicable code.

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/myButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:text="Send" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/myButton"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:text="Who's there?" />
```

MainActivity.java

```
    package com.example.mytest;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {


private Socket socket;

private static final int SERVERPORT = 5001;
private static final String SERVER_IP = "SERVER_ADDRESS (Assume this is correct)";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
}

public void onClick(View view) {
    try {


        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        //This is where the problem is!
        //EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        //String str = et.getText().toString();


        String str = "Who's there?";

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                true);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));


        //Send "str" to server
        out.println(str);

        //Get string from server NOT WORKING EITHER
        String in_str = in.readLine();
        tv.setText(in_str);


    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

class ClientThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);

            socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

    }
```

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Try adding `out.flush()` below `out.println(str);`

Comment: Thanks for your comment, unfortunately it still doesn't send.